# Custom Binding - init keeps getting called

Tags: knockout.js, ko-custom-binding

I've been trying to use both a custom component, and then a custom binding within Knockout to render a small visualization. I got this working, but realized the solution wasn't ideal. My custom binding is supposed to handle changes to the data by using transitions.

[image]

If a new item appears, say `E` , I'd like it to transition in. I also need to update the green stroke round each circle everytime the binding changes.

My issue is that when my `context` binding updates in the code below, that the whole binding seems to re-initialize. I think Knockout underneath is removing the DOM for the previous `context` and re-renders the entire lot - this causes each circle to grow and triggers the new item animation.

```
ko.components.register("context", {
    // Assume that the view model given to us is already observable, having had a ko.mapping.fromJS() applied or similar
    viewModel: function (vm) {
        this.context = vm;
    },
    template: '<div class="card context-card" data-bind="contextViz: context">\
                <!-- ko if: context && context.types.length === 0 -->\
                    <div>Please make a selection to view contextual information here.</div>\
                <!-- /ko -->\
               </div>\
               '
});
```

I'm wondering if there's anything I can do to prevent this. Essentially I want the old `context` binding to just update but I'm not sure if there's a way to do so.

I've added a code snippet to illustrate. Here `init called` is logged each time an update occurs, I only want this to log once, and `update called` to be logged many times.

```js
var count = 0;

ko.bindingHandlers.contextViz = {
    init: function() {
        console.log("init called");
    },
    update: function() {
        console.log("update called");
    }
};

ko.components.register("context", {
    viewModel: function (vm) {
        this.context = vm;
    },
    template: '<div class="card context-card" data-bind="contextViz: context">'
});

var vm = {
   context: ko.observable({ count: count })
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);

setInterval(function() {
  vm.context({ count: count + 1 });  
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="component: { name: 'context', params: $root.context }"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are directly using your `context` property as the `params` of your computed KO will re-render the whole computed when the `context` changes.

The usual practice is to pass in an object with some properties as the `params` so when the properties of this object changes the component does not completely re-rendered.

So you need to change your HTMl to:

```
<div data-bind="component: { name: 'context', params: { context: $root.context }}"></div>
```

And in your computed constructor just write:

```
viewModel: function (params) {
    this.context = params.context;
},
```

```js
var count = 0;

ko.bindingHandlers.contextViz = {
init: function() {
    document.getElementById("log").innerHTML += "init called\n";
},
update: function(e,v) {
    console.log(ko.unwrap(v())) // make a dependency so it will be called when the bound observable changes
    document.getElementById("log").innerHTML += "update called\n";
}
};

ko.components.register("context", {
viewModel: function (params) {
    this.context = params.context;
},
template: '<div class="card context-card" data-bind="contextViz: context">'
});

var vm = {
   context: ko.observable({ count: count })
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);

setInterval(function() {
  vm.context({ count: ++count });  
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="component: { name: 'context', params: { context: $root.context }}"></div>
<div>log:</div>
<pre id="log"></pre>
```